# How to get correct response from passport.authenticate('local')?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, mern, passport-local

I am sending this POST request but not getting response, thunder client says BAD REQUEST.
(Used passport-local in node.js)

```
.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local"), loginUser);
```

Problem is with passport.authenticate("local") text, when added to query for authentication, it shows BAD REQUEST.

where loginUser is a controller function to get the status

```
const loginUser = async (req, res) => {
  try{
    res.json({ status: "success!!" });
  }
  catch(err)
  {
    res.status(400).json(err);
  }
};
```

what to do in such case?

I am expecting successful authentication so that I can allow my middleware to function on other pages of web app.